# What is the correct way to use Typescript without bundling?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

Currently I bundle my apps using WebPack into a single file. I have a library which contains a set of components that have large transitive dependencies (e.g. ag-grid). If a project isn't using all the components, it still has to download and load them.

Most of the time its my code that is changing rather than changing the transitive libraries so it would appear as though I should be able to get away with just using the evergreen-browser inbuilt ES6 modules and keep it as separate files (with eTag caching) rather than bundling into a single app.js.

I have a project structure like this:

```
/
/lib
/lib/src/ag-grid-wrapper.ts
/lib/src/index.ts
/lib/package.json
/project
/project/src/index.ts
/project/package.json
```

/lib/src/index.ts:

```
export { createWrappedGrid } from "./ag-grid-wrapper";
```

/project/package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "lib": "../lib/"
...
```

/project/src/index.ts:

```
import { createWrappedGrid } from "lib";

createWrappedGrid();
```

This compiles, but there are two problems:

1. The compiled code contains this: `import { createWrappedGrid } from "lib";`, it's not transpired into anything that the browser can understand and obviously it doesn't know what "lib" means. I did a quick google and you can use something called an import map, but naively I expected the Typescript compiler to do this automagically - does it and I've missed the option?
2. The node_modules and transitive node modules (ag-grid) aren't in the output folder. I imagine there is some sort of flag/extension/tool to make this happen.

Comment: You are most likely looking to still bundle your modules into a single file. You can however use [the `externals` configuration option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) to tell webpack not to bundle your dependencies.

Comment: No, the TypeScript compiler does not automagically rewrite module imports. It doesn't know where and how you will be serving those files on the web.

Comment: Vite is built around a strategy like this (rapid transpilation using esbuild direct to es modules, aliasing as necessary to actual URLs but without changing the module structure). It has built-in typescript support. In my personal experience this is the most valuable when deployed locally and doing development, and I rely on bundling to a single file for actual deployment. https://vitejs.dev/guide/why